# CSS_Stroke to text

Tags: html, css, text, fonts, stroke

Are there any ways in CSS to give stroke to text (not in SVG) with different colors?

Target example:

[image: target example]

I've tried this [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke-color), but seems that when one change font size to 1em or smaller, stroke "eat" all figure line, see example below

```css
/*p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 48pt;
  color: aqua;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #ff0000;
}

text {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: aqua;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #ff0000;
} ----------- initial code */


* {font-family:
        sans-serif}
        
div {
background-color:#D1ECE3}
        
p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 48pt;
  color: black;
  text-shadow:3px 0 0 white,0 3px 0 white,-3px 0 0 white,0 -3px 0 white;
}

#px1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: black;
  text-shadow:1px 0 0 white,0 1px 0 white,-1px 0 0 white,0 -1px 0 white;
}

#px2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: black;
  text-shadow:2px 0 0 white,0 2px 0 white,-2px 0 0 white,0 -2px 0 white;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Stroke, huge font size, shadow 3px</p>
<text id='px1'>Stroke, small font size, shadow 1px</text></br>
<text id='px2'>Stroke, smaller font size, shadow 2px</text>
<div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting. 1em is probably something like 16px. Then you take 2x3px for the stroke on what will be a small proportion of the font-size (e.g. the upright of that capital T). What do you want it to look like?

Comment: I've edited my snippet. I want font 2nd has font color visible, similar as it is now for the 1st line. But seems this method is working only for big font sizes (

Comment: You shuld use text-shadow. Text-stroke takes the space from the text. text-shadow:1px 0 0 red,0 1px 0 red,-1px 0 0 red,0 -1px 0 red;

Comment: It's all working as it should, even on the small text size. But the problem is, as @Tomtom has pointed out, the stroke is actually within the actual text, so on that upright in the T for example, 6px is being used up for stroke (which is probably more than the width of that upright) so it ends up looking a blobby mess.

Comment: I've tried your option, @Tomtom, but it's still looking weird. I also added target image as an example

Comment: On my browser, I see the example in a serif font, and trying to compare that with a sans-serif font in the picture. Also, using red on a white background, as opposed to white on a greenish background, can make comparison difficult. I suggest making your code closer to your target.

Comment: Yes, it looks better, thx. Are there any other options except shadow one?